# What does ‘regimen’ mean in English grammar?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I happened to find that definition of the word, ‘regimen’ has the meaning of ‘governing word’ such as prepositions (sic from Reader’s English Japanese Dictionary) besides a popular notion of ‘a set of rules about food and exercise or medical treatment to stay healthy, or improve one’s health.’

What does ‘regimen’ as a grammatical term mean? What are they? How do they function? Are they different from simple modifiers such as adjectives and subordinate clauses?

Comment: I came across it in a book on biblical figures of speech, ie the figure antimereia...see e.w. Bullinger Very interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary’s third definition of *regimen* is:

> *Grammar*. The relation of a word, clause, etc. to the word that governs
>   it. Also: a case, word, or phrase so governed by another word. Now
>   *rare*.

I have never come across it with this meaning myself. Since the OED describes it as rare it is probably best avoided.